# BitSet field type in solr

Tags: solr

I am new to solr and I apologize if I am not using the right terms in my question. I want to use solr to store and search for some chemistry data. For each molecule (represented as a string), I can convert it into a bitset representation (fixed length). To search for the molecule, the similarity is based on bits comparison. Since there will be large amount of data, I want to make the search faster so I imagine I need to index these bitsets. I want to write a custom FieldType, a custom Similarity. The FieldType will automatically convert the text representation of the molecule into a BitSet and store/index it. So my question is, is this possible, or is there anything that already in solr that can store/index bitsets?

Thank you!